# Swift: Access tuple elements using variables/arguments?

Tags: swift

Here's the [generic version of the] situation:

```
let tuple: (first: Int, second: Int, third: Int) // tuple.0 is equivalent to  tuple.first

enum TupleIndex: Int { 
    case first = 0, second, third 
}

func selectTupleElement (index: TupleIndex) {
    let indexNum = index.rawValue
    let tupleElement = tuple.indexNum // Oh noooooo!!!
}
```

The compiler reads the problem spot, indicated in the last line above, as "the `indexNum` property or element of `tuple`" (which of course doesn't exist) rather than "the element of `tuple` at the index equal to the value of `indexNum`"

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, using tuples?

Comment: I've thought of a way:
`let arrayInstead = [Int]()`

Comment: Why not use arrays? What is the benefit of using tuples for you?

Comment: @Sweeper, I want to use tuples so that I can name the elements and refer to the elements by those name-indexes instead of the number-indexes I'd need in an array. However, I've figured out a solution, which is to create variables equal to the index numbers and then I can say <br>
`let first = 1`<br>
`let indexNum = first`<br>
`let selection = array[indexNum]`<br>
<br><br>
But I'm curious if it can be done with tuples. Just curious!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* make use of runtime introspection to conditionally extract the `n`:th member of a tuple *of fixed size and same-type members* (e.g. below: implemented for tuple of arity 3 with uniform typed members) and (conditionally) convert it to the member's type. E.g.:

```
func selectTupleElementFor<T>(memberNumber: Int, inTuple tuple: (T, T, T)) -> T? {
    return Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children.enumerated()
        .first(where: { $0.0 == memberNumber - 1 }).flatMap { $1.1 as? T }
}

// example usage
let tuple: (first: Int, second: Int, third: Int) = (10, 20, 30)
if let tupleMember = selectTupleElementFor(memberNumber: 2, inTuple: tuple) {
    print(tupleMember) // 20
}
```

Or, using your `TupleIndex` `enum`:

```
enum TupleIndex: Int { 
    case first = 0, second, third 
}

func selectTupleElementFor<T>(tupleIndex: TupleIndex, inTuple tuple: (T, T, T)) -> T? {
    return Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children.enumerated()
        .first(where: { $0.0 == tupleIndex.rawValue }).flatMap { $1.1 as? T }
}

// example usage
let tuple: (first: Int, second: Int, third: Int) = (10, 20, 30)
if let tupleMember = selectTupleElementFor(tupleIndex: .second, inTuple: tuple) {
    print(tupleMember) // 20
}
```

Comment: ... and then I realized the suggested dupe target contains a solution with the similar introspection approach, written by myself, doh xD Anyway, will leave the answer above as it shows an example using the OPs own `TupleIndex` type and also use a slightly different implementation of the introspection than in the (non-accepted) answer of the dupe target.

Comment: Note that I believe that advancing the index for `children` itself (such as in your other answer) is a better approach than using `first(where:)` with `enumerated()` in this case, as the former can take advantage of O(1) indexing for random access collections, whereas the latter can't (although I don't work with `Mirror` at all that often, so don't know under what circumstances it returns a `children` collection that is or isn't random accessible – perhaps you know? :) ).

Comment: @Hamish the `children` call returns a type-erased collection wrapper [`AnyCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anycollection) which I believe is not random access (even if the underlying type-erased collection is); compare with the type-erased collection wrapper [`AnyRandomAccessCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyrandomaccesscollection) that is. Anyhow, since we're working with introspection over a tuple (with a a function statically specifying a fixed arity), I don't believe random access vs `O(n)` traversal should be an issue here ...

Comment: ... unless the "tuple index access" itself is part of some HPC appl.: but it wouldn't be sound to use runtime introsp. in such an application (or in the one above, for that part: just a technical approach, but any native random-access collection would be preferable: or simply an array of a custom `struct` type). Leaving aside random access, I agree that the other solution has other upsides vs this one as well: generally easier (/better) semantics, even if I personally like (and jump at!) every occation I get to use the neat `map` or `flatMap` methods of `Optional` :) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Very good point about the tuple length being fixed anyway so both approaches are technically O(1) – this definitely isn't as big of an issue as I might have made it out to be (I just saw the use of `first(where:)` to index, and twitched slightly :P). Although note that `AnyCollection` can still be random access if the underlying collection is – it just forwards calls to the indexing methods to the underlying collection at the end of the day :)

Comment: And yes, *completely* agree with you that if OP can use an array to do this, he definitely should – tuples aren't meant for long-term data storage, merely for transient data.

Comment: @Hamish Good point about `AnyCollection`'s forwarding. In this particular case (`Mirror.children`) I'm unsure if the underlying collection does allow random access however (since I'm unsure what the underlying collection actually is when reflecting over e.g. a tuple: an array?): based on [the discussion on the lang. ref. of `Mirror.Children`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/mirror/children), we can may _upgrade_ the non-random-access type erased collect. wrapper to one that is type erased by allow random access. Might look into the implementation details of this, at another time :)

Comment: Yeah, I had a brief look over the implementation of `Mirror` and couldn't see much – only that, for example, types that conform to `CustomReflectable` can use the `Mirror(_:unlabeledChildren:displayStyle:)` initialiser to provide their own `children`, in which case they would control whether the `Mirror` returns `children` that is random accessible or not. However, I didn't really look into it more than that. Anyway, thanks for the interesting discussion as always – congrats on your gold [swift] badge btw (hopefully I'll get there in the near future :) )

Comment: @Hamish Ah, nice to know, still haven't really used custom mirrors except for some obscure answer here on SO. Likewise, I always learn something from them. Thanks! Closing this thread was in fact my first use of the dupehammer :) I see you're not so far off yourself, so sooner rather than later, is my guess! :)